# assign column names in pandas from pd.series an loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say my df:

```
A User1 User2
1 0       0
2 1       1
3 1       0
```

And I want create another column in dataframe that was sum of column `user1` plus `user`
So it's easy:  `df['sum_result_Newcolum'] = df['user1']+df['user2']`.
So it looks like this:

```
 A User1 User2   sum_result_Newcolum
    1 0       0   0
    2 1       1   2
    3 1       0   1
```

But I have panda.series look like this:

```
    0
0   AC.IR
1   AC.PO
2   B.0
3   B.1
```

end etc.
So I want create `for` statement there run through pd.series and add value to column name. So that issue, I try something like this without any success:

```
df['sum_result_'+ {cv_details.get(0)}]=df['user1']+df['user2']
df['sum_result_'+ cv_details.get(0)]=df['user1']+df['user2']
df['sum_result_'+ cv_details[0]]=df['user1']+df['user2']
df['sum_result_'+ cv_details.iloc[0]]=df['user1']+df['user2']
```

All time best result is column name: "sum_result_Action..."

Maybe solution convert pd.series to frame?

Comment: what's your expected output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it's not 100% clear what your expected result is.
- If you want a new column for each value in your series

  - [assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) ****kwargs** can be built as a **dict** comprehension
  - from your sample code, you have defined a static calculation **User1 + User2**

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""A User1 User2
1 0       0
2 1       1
3 1       0"""), sep="\s+")

cv_details = pd.Series(['AC.IR', 'AC.PO', 'B.0', 'B.1'])

df.assign(**{f"sum_result_{v}":df["User1"]+df["User2"] for v in cv_details})
```

|  | A | User1 | User2 | sum_result_AC.IR | sum_result_AC.PO | sum_result_B.0 | sum_result_B.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |